# Changing font size of pdfptable

Tags: vb.net, itext

How do I set the font for a pdfptable?

Comment: is there something simpler than what you guys are showing me? perhaps just setfont(size 12) or something?

Comment: no, you have to register a font first.

Comment: Like Jason says.  The PdfPTable object gives you a lot more flexibility than the regular Table object, but it is more complex to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must set the font in each cell when you're creating a phrase:

```
Dim yourFont As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont( _
  Current.Server.MapPath("~/fonts/somefont.TTF"), _
  BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
Dim mainFont As New Font(yourFont, SOME_FONT_SIZE, Font.NORMAL)

Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("some text", mainFont))
yourTable.Add(cell)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a 'Base Font' object which is a little different than a regular font object in iTextSharp.  You assign the font to each element (phrase, paragraph, etc.) that you create for the PdfPTable.

```
Dim bfR As iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont
  bfR = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont("verdana.ttf", iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
```

I'm using the IDENTITY_H property here so that support for other alphabets is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute PdfPTable has a property DefaultCell which you can set the defaults properties of your PdfPCell elements:

```
//C#
tableInstance.DefaultCell.Phrase = new Phrase() { Font = yourFont };
```

Comment: Could someone confirm this? Much nicer than repeatedly setting it for every single cell+phrase.